# Tkinter grid_size() functions misbehavior

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am writing a GUI in tkinter and there are rows added on go.
I need a button to remain on the bottom of the screen all the time.
In my program it works for 12 times and then the button gets stock as other lines are being added on. In the function I cut out to place here it works for 6 times...
I'm using a RPI and python 3.8.
Here is the code:

```
import tkinter as tk

segments = [] #list of segments
class segment:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root    #necessary for future reference
        segments.append(self)
        i = segments.index(self)
        lable = tk.Label(root,text="Here is your 
        segment").grid(row=i,columnspan=5)
        

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Root")
rootsegment = segment(root)
button = tk.Button(root, text='Add a segment', width=10, 
command=lambda: segment(root)).grid(row=root.grid_size()[0])
root.mainloop()
```

Thanks to everybody

Comment: `row=root.grid_size()[0]` is going to produce a value (zero, I think) *once*, during startup of your program - this expression isn't going to magically change the row number of your Button as other items are added to the grid.  If you want the Button to always be below the grid, then *don't make it part of the grid at all*.  Instead, have only the Button and a Frame directly in the root window, and add your segments to that Frame instead of the root.

Comment: row=root.grid_size()[0] returns the first (number 0) value of grid_size tuple, the grid size is growing as lines are being added. Making a separate frame sounds like a good idea. Just not yet explaining how to work right with grid_size.  Thank you.

Comment: If you evaluated that expression later, it would indeed give you the current size of the grid.  But that isn't what you're doing with it - you're evaluating it exactly one time, before there are any other widgets in the grid.  It's exactly the same as writing `row=0`.

Comment: So why does it work for 5 rounds?

Comment: If you print the result of `grid_size()` before creating the button, you will get `(5, 1)` because `rootsegment = segment(root)` created a label at row=0 and column=0 with columnspan=5.  That means you have created a row of 5 columns.  Therefore the button will be put at row=5 and column=0.  After 5 button clicks, the last label overlaps/blocks the button and so the button cannot be clicked anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much acw1668 and  jasonharper!
Based on what you wrote the answer is as following:
grid_size() returns *first empty (columns,rows)* and my mistake was using grid_size()[0] for row number, I should of used grid_size()[1] instead.
And the other mistake was as  jasonharper has mentioned that I called it once, relying on mainloop() to go over the call.